# How to exclude files and directories from being counted toward additions and deletions metrics when merging on GitHub Enterprise?

Tags: github

I'm trying to get better analytics of how many lines of codes have changed during a commit and/or a pull-request merge. But auto-generated files, third party libraries and others get included the additions and deletions metrics.

I tried changing the .gitattributes file to include binary,diff=nodiff -diff and other tags. That changed the way GitHub Desktop displayed the diffs. But did not effect the web interface result when trying to merge the pull-request. I'm running a GitHub Enterprise Server. What's the trick?